# i want to create a friendly url in php

Tags: php

i want to create my site a friendly url and this is my code.

the problem with this code is when i click about us link the url became localhost/php_friendly_url/about/12 it its correct but when i click main link the url became like this localhost/php_friendly_url/about/main can you help me to correct the my code

please help me with my problem.

**main.php**

```
    <html>
      <body>
         <h1>Main Page</h1>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="main">Main</a></li>
             <li><a href="about/12">About US</a></li>
         </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
   include 'class/friendlyUrl.php'; 
   $url = new friendlyUrl('/php_friendly_url');

   if(!$url->segment(1))
       $page = 'main';
   else
       $page = $url->segment(1);

   switch($page) {    
   case 'main':

      include 'main.php';
      break;

   case 'about':

      include 'about.php';
      break;

   default:   
    echo '404 not found';
    break;
  } 
?>
```

**friendlyUrl.php**

```
<?php

    class {     
        var $site_path;         
        function __construct($site_path){           
            $this->site_path = $this->removeSlash($site_path);          
        }       

        function __toString(){          
            return $this->site_path;            
        }

        private function removeSlash($string){          
            if( $string[strlen($string) - 1 ] == '/' )              
                $string = rtrim($string, '/');  
                return $string;         
        }

        function segment($segment){         
            $url = str_replace($this->site_path, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            $url = explode('/', $url);              

            if( isset($url[$segment]) ){                
                return $url[$segment];              
            }
            else                    
                return false;

            return $url;            
        }   
    }
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `<li><a href="/main">Main</a></li>` note forward slash in href

Comment: Forward slash is good if the website is in the root. Eg: http://localhost but if he is using multiple projects like http://localhost/supersecret_project, /about/12 would not work since it would link to localhost/about/12 and not localhost/supersecret_project/about/12

Comment: You should use your site url before link. Like @Magic-Mouse said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is write "/" at the beginning of your URL like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/main">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about/12">About US</a></li>
</ul>
```

that's it no "special" PHP code required ;)

If your website is not in the root folder, but lets say in the "test" sub-folder, then what I usually do is create constant in some "config" file (included in all files) like:

```
define( 'URL', 'http://mywebdomain.com/test' );
```

and then use this constant in all links:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo URL ?>/main">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo URL ?>/about/12">About US</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter, that has the same style of linking i solve this by adding  in front of all links.

```
<html>
  <body>
     <h1>Main Page</h1>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main">Main</a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about/12">About US</a></li>
     </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Though base_url() is from codeigniter, not from PHP you could make something similar your self.

Edit:

The easiest way to make base_url() would be having a constant that you manually updates depending on environment:

```
function base_url(){
  return "http://localhost/";
}
```

There is lots of more advanced self detecting solutions, i would suggest you use google to find one apropriate if the above doesnt suit your needs.